# Can't properly post reCaptcha token to backend to verify it

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, post, fetch

I've encountered a problem trying to send the reCaptcha auth token back to the backend of my server build on node and express, it displays an internal error 500 on the current method I'm trying to follow to post it. The code on the frontend looks like this:

```
const captcha = document.querySelector('#g-recaptcha-response').value;

console.log(captcha);            

fetch('/submit', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-type':'application/json'
    },
    body:JSON.stringify({captcha: captcha})
})
.then((res) => res.json())
.then((data) =>{
    console.log(data);
    alert(data.msg);
})
.catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

And the backend like this:

```
router.post('/submit', validateToken, (req, res) => {

  const secretKey = 'this is my secret key';
  const userKey = req.params.captcha;

  const verifyUrl = `https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=${secretKey}&response=${req.body.captcha}&remoteip=${req.socket.remoteAddress}`;

  request(verifyUrl, (err, response, body) => {
    body = JSON.parse(body);

    if(body.success !== undefined && !body.success){
      return res.json({"success": false, "msg":"Ha habido un error, intentalo de nuevo"});
    }else{
      return res.json({"success": true, "msg":"Has ganado 50 monedas!"});
    }
  });
```

It currently seems like it never reaches the backend, I've tried to post also with jquery and ajax but none of them seemed to reach the backend, and this one just gives back a generic response to the client from the error 500. I really think the issue is on my post request on the client side even though I might be wrong. Any help is much appreciated.

Also, point out that the client token is correct on the console.log(captcha).

Thanks a lot to anybody who can give me a hint on what I'm doing wrong.

Edit: Here is the code for validating the token, purposed to make the session expire every 30 minutes.

```
function validateToken(req, res, next) {
  console.log('Se intenta acceder a un area que requiere validacion de Token.')
  var token = req.cookies.token;

  if (token) {
    jwt.verify(token, app.get('TOKEN_SECRET'), (err, user) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log('El token no es valido, eliminando y redirigiendo al login.');
        res.clearCookie('token');
        res.sendFile('/login.html', { root: publicDirectory + '/login' })
      } else {
        console.log('Token valido, se genera otro para mantener los 30 minutos de persistencia.')
        req.user = user;
        res.clearCookie('token')
        if(req.user.iat) delete req.user.iat
        if(req.user.exp) delete req.user.exp
        const token = jwt.sign(Object.assign({}, req.user), app.get('TOKEN_SECRET'), { expiresIn: 1800 });
        res.cookie('token', token, { httpOnly: true });
        next()
      }
    });
  } else {
    console.log('No hay token, redirigiendo al Login.')
    res.sendFile('/login.html', { root: publicDirectory + '/login' })
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show  code for `validateToken` middleware function ?

Comment: Sure, it is purposed for the control of sessions that have to expire every 30 minutes as a requisite for the web app